# Better way of using vue instance in vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I just begun working with **vuex**, i came to a point where i had to use **vue instance** inside vuex. I was using a package called **vue-toasted** and to use to it inside vue application and wrote the following code inside **main.js**

```
import Toasted from 'vue-toasted';

const ToastedOptions = {
  position: 'bottom-center',
  duration: 1500,
  theme: 'bubble'
};

Vue.use(Toasted, ToastedOptions);
```

This worked fine inside **.vue** files. but was not working inside **store.js**.

Then i tried declaring same code inside **store.js**, which i didn't work either. I had to access the **vue instance**, so i came up with a couple of solutions:

1. Passing the vue instance as **payload** to the **actions**
2. Directly accessing **vue instance** through **this._vm**

Both pattern worked perfectly, but there must be a better way of doing that, a cleaner approach for clean code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Vuex is a state management system**, it's goal is to **store your state** (your data; employees, cars, application state, user details etc) **Not manipulate the DOM**. This is what you have vue for.

As you see yourself, there is a ocean of ways to tackle this problem, but I think the best general way to fix this, would be to trigger back some "event" to Vue.

An example could be to have an object in your state: `toast`

```
const state = {
  toast: null,
  cars: [{...}, {...}, {...}]
}
```

Then when you are going to toast something, you can commit(mutate) the toast in the state to include some metadata for your real toast.

```
const state = {
  toast: {
    title: 'An important message',
    options: {
      position: 'bottom-center',
      duration: 1500,
      theme: 'bubble'
    }
  },
  cars: [{...}, {...}, {...}]
}
```

In vue, you could for example have a watcher on the vuex toast state to wait for changes.
Once the `state.toast` changes from `null` to an object, you can run the function to trigger the actual toast (in vue), then when the toast is done, you can clear the toast object from the state (telling vue there is no more toasts)

*Pseudo example vue file:*

```
import { mapState } from 'vuex';
new Vue({
  computed: {
    ...mapState({
      toast: state => state.toast
    })
  },
  watch: {
    toast(toastData) {
      if (toastData === null) {
        return;
      }
      
      this.toastMessage(toastData);
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toastMessage(toastData) {
      this.toasted.show(toastData.title, toastData.options);
      window.setTimeout(this.resetToast, toastData.options.duration)
    },
    resetToast() {
      this.$store.commit('CLEAR_TOAST'); // mutation in vuex to set state.toast = null
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: I have implemented this same thing for https://github.com/avil13/vue-sweetalert2. 
You can find whole demo here: https://github.com/Uraharadono/CallbackFromVuexAction